# How to build a query involving several different tables with different relationships

Tags: mysql, sql, database, dql

I'm currently trying to write a query which involves 5 main tables, 2 of which are referring to a 3rd with foreign keys, but not relating to each-other... and one of the first 2 tables is the main subject of the query. Here's a basic synopsis.

```
instance             user 
--------             ----
id                   id
name                 name
user_id


def                  def_map
---                  ------
id                   id
name                 instance_id
user_id              def_id


def_data
--------
id
name
def_id
user_id
```

What I want to do is get a list of all of the 'def_map's for a single user. In each row I'd like the associated def_data to be displayed as well. So the rows would be like:

```
instance.id, def.id, def.name, def_data.name, user.id
```

I can figure out how to get all info except def_data.name in the result, or all info except for instance.id ... but can't figure out how to get then all together using one query. Is it possible? I think part of the problem is I don't know if there is a special word that describes this type of query so I would know what to read up on.

I'm using DQL, but examples in SQL would be just as useful. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL%29

Comment: I'm familiar with JOINS but this is not a simple join. It's possible that it's some special type of join, and if so - my question was what is it called? Because i've read through JOINs and have been unable to find a solution to this kind of problem.

Comment: You would simply be JOINing more than one 2 tables, I have no special name for that. Also, I think you db model is a bit too complex; for example, why do you have `def` and `def_data` which seem to be the same thing?

Comment: But, the problem is I do not know how to JOIN in another table which is not already linked in the chain of referenced tables. ie. `SELECT instance.id AS instance_id, def_map.def_id AS def_id, user.id AS user_Id FROM def_map JOIN def_map.def_id AS def, JOIN def_map.instance_id AS instance, JOIN instance.user_id AS user WHERE def_map.instance_id == '$instance_id'` ... This query _(i'm sure there are errors, but just for a general idea of what I'm getting at)_ has a chain of references to every table involved, **except** for the def_data table, which I can't get at.

Comment: As for the complexity... the def_data table has a more complicated purpose and  undergoes complete wipes quite often, whereas the def table is very static and the rows are never removed once created. - So they have to be separate, and def cannot refer to def_data since the rows may be removed & recreated at any time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can pull the data individually using 2 queries you simply need to `UNION` them together

```
    SELECT user.id, i.id, d.id, dd.name 
    FROM user u  
    INNER JOIN instance i ON u.id=i.user_id
    INNER JOIN def d ON dm.user_id = u.id 
    INNER JOIN def_data dd ON dd.def_id = d.id  
    UNION ALL  
    SELECT u.id, i.id AS instance_id, d.id, dd.name  
    FROM instance i 
    INNER JOIN user u ON u.id=i.user_id
    INNER JOIN defmap dm ON dm.instance_id=i.id  
    INNER JOIN def_data dd ON dd.def_id=dm.def_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select I.id, D.id, D.name, DD.name, U.id
from user U inner join instance  I on I.user_id =  U.id
Inner join def D on D.user_id = U.id
inner join def_map DM on DM.def_id = D.id AND I.id = DM.instance_id
inner join def_data DD on DD.def_id = D.id AND U.id = DD.user_id
```

Test data:

```
USER                        
+----+-------------------------+
| id | name                    |
+----+-------------------------+
|  1 | Name1                   |
+----+-------------------------+                
Instance 

+----+------+---------+
| id | name | user_id |
+----+------+---------+
|  1 | I1   |       1 |
+----+------+---------+    
def_map    
+--------+-------------+--------+
|   id   | instance_id | def_id |
+--------+-------------+--------+
|      1 |           1 |  1     |
+--------+-------------+--------+

def
+--------------+------+
| id | name | user_id |
+--------------+------+
|  1 | df1  |      1  |
+--------------+------+

def_data
+--------+------+--------+---------+
|     id | name | def_id | user_id |
+--------+------+--------+---------+
|      1 | dd1  |      1 |       1 |
+--------+------+--------+---------+
```

Result

```
+-------------+--------+----------+---------------+---------+
| instance.id | def.id | def.name | def_data.name | user.id |
+-------------+--------+----------+---------------+---------+
|           1 |      1 | df1      | dd1           |       1 |
+-------------+--------+----------+---------------+---------+
```

[image: visual representation]